# How to make CMAKE find specific version of lib curl on OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, curl, cmake

Question is: How do I get CMAKE to set/make the CURL_INCLUDE_DIR be "/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.75.0/include/"?

No matter what I do, CMAKE only finds the Xcode lib version/location.

My CMAKE file contains:

```
set(CURL_ROOT_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.75.0/include/)
find_package(curl REQUIRED)
message(STATUS ">>> CURL Dir Found: " ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

No matter what I've tried, the above CMAKE code will result in a "CURL_INCLUDE_DIR" of

> "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include

Note, utilizing  "include(findcurl)" instead of "find_package(curl REQUIRED)" gives same result.

I've resorted to adding

> set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-I/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.57.0/include
>   -L/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.57.0/lib")

to get CMAKE to actually utilize the lib version/location that I want. Is there a better way that I'm failing to figure out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cmake `FindCURL` module (at least in the version I have, 3.5.1) does not make reference to `CURL_ROOT_DIR` anywhere, so I don't believe setting that variable will have any effect.

In fact the `FindCURL` module is really quite basic and doesn't offer any means for customising where to look, which means it will be looking only in "standard" paths (eg `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib` etc)

You can, however, use [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html) which takes a `PATHS` argument.

```
set(CURL_PATH "/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.75.0")

find_library(
        LIB_CURL
        NAMES
            curl
        PATHS 
            ${CURL_PATH}/lib)
```

At this point you will have a variable `${LIB_CURL}` which points to the location of `libcurl`

**Link against the library and set the include path:**

You can then just link against `${LIB_CURL}` directly, and manually specify the include path for your target too, such as:

```
add_executable(
        foo
        main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
        foo
        ${LIB_CURL})

target_include_directories(
        foo
        SYSTEM 
        PRIVATE "${CURL_PATH}/include")
```

**IMPORTED library target:**

Another option, if you want to be fancy, is to create an `IMPORTED` library target using `${LIB_CURL}`, and set the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` on that target, so consumers get the include path set automatically.

```
add_library(
        libcurl 
        IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(
        libcurl 
        PROPERTIES 
            IMPORTED_LOCATION "${LIB_CURL}")

set_target_properties(
        libcurl 
        PROPERTIES
            INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CURL_PATH}/include")
```

Now you will just be able to link against target `libcurl` directly, and your app will automatically have its include paths updated

```
add_executable(
        foo 
        main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
        foo
        libcurl)
```